# update_post_meta() not updating

Tags: wp-query, loop, metabox, post-meta

I'm saving API data as metabox data, and I'm attempting to update metabox data on import. So the Title, content data will always update. But I can't seem to be able to use the ID to update the metabox!! Also, adding data for the first time will ALWAYS WORK, but updating the metabox data will NEVER WORK...

Should I try deleting the metabox data and then re-adding it? Does anyone have suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

```
// check against custom id field to see if post already exists
    $room_id = $room['id'];
// meta query to check if the Gid already exists
$duplicate_check = new \WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'room',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'room_id',
            'value' => $room_id
        )
    ),
) );

/*
 * Construct arguments to use for wp_insert_post()
 */
$args = array();

if ( $duplicate_check->have_posts() ) {

    $duplicate_check->the_post();
    $args['ID'] = get_the_ID(); // existing post ID (otherwise will insert new)

}

$args['post_title']   = $room['name']; // post_title
$args['post_content'] = ! empty( $room['description'] ) ? $room['description'] : ''; // post_content
$args['post_status'] = 'publish'; // default is draft
$args['post_type']    = 'room';

/*
 * Create the Room and grab post id (for post meta insertion)
 */
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $args );

// Insert data into custom fields
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'room_id', $room['id'], true);
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'room_description', $room['description'], true);
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'room_image', $room['image'], true);
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'room_capacity', $room['capacity'], true);

// Raw data for development
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'room_raw_data', $room, true);
```

Comment: You need to remove `,true` from your `update_post_meta()` cals. The 4th argument for `update_post_meta` is `prev_value`, so you are in essence saying "Only update the postmeta for this post ID, for meta key `room_id`, put `$room['id']` as the value, and cancel all that unless the previous value was `true`.

Comment: amazing @WebElaine, that **worked** thank you so much!!!!